# Working with write queues and multi threading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a process running in a separate thread which reads data over Ethernet and raises an event for each read. Then, this data is processed over a tree of classes. At the top of my class tree, I want to store the processed data to SQL tables. This read rate can be rather fast and often at times but on average its slower than my write rate to SQL. This is why I want a queue. Also I want my window not to freeze, so I want a separate thread.

The code below works but I'm fairly inexperienced in multi threading, is this a good and robust way to accomplish my task?

```
Private addLogQueue As New Queue
Private dequeueing As Boolean = False
Public Sub addLogHandler(ByVal machineName As String, ByVal LogTime As Date, ByVal EventLog As String, ByVal EventValue As String)
    addLogQueue.Enqueue("INSERT INTO ... some SQL CODE")
    Dim Thread1 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf addLog)
    Thread1.Start
End Sub
Private Sub addLog()
    If Not dequeueing Then
        dequeueing = True
        While addLogQueue.Count <> 0
            Try
                SQLCon.Open()
                SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(addLogQueue.Dequeue(), SQLCon)
                SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                SQLCon.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    SQLCon.Close()
                End If
            End Try
        End While
        dequeueing = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Where they will probably point out that you've forgotten to do `SQLConn.Dispose()`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton He should, more likely, be using a `using` directive instead. (There's almost never a need to write it like this.)

Comment: @EBrown I intended to leave the bulk of it to Code Review where the merit of using a queue could also be discussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refer you to the article: [Beginners Guide to Threading](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26148/Beginners-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-of-n).  Also, for performance reasons you may want to keep the thread open, and the database connection open and simply use a wait event to determine if the queue should be checked for more entries.  See this article: [An Overview of Synchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964(v=vs.110).aspx).  Keeping the connection open would really depend on the frequency of arrival of messages.  Very frequent: keep connection open, intermittent: Close after use.

```
Dim Thread1 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf addLog)
Private Shared mre As New ManualResetEvent(False)
Private addLogQueue As New Queue
Private shutDown as boolean = false

Public Sub Main   
    Thread1.Start    
End Sub
Public Sub addLogHandler(ByVal machineName As String, ByVal LogTime As Date, ByVal EventLog As String, ByVal EventValue As String)
    addLogQueue.Enqueue("INSERT INTO ... some SQL CODE")
    mre.Set()
End Sub

Private Sub addLog()
    dim cmdString as String
    Try
        Using SQLCon as New SQLConnection
            SQLCon.Open()
            While Not shutDown
                mre.WaitOne()
                mre.Reset()
                While addLogQueue.Count <> 0
                    cmdString = addLogQueue.Dequeue()
                    SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(cmdString, SQLCon)
                    SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End While
            End While
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        My.Application.Log.WriteException(ex,TraceEventType.Error, cmdString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Also, you may want to lookup a few articles on writing services as this sort of thing works very much better as a service, if you want the program to do unattended monitoring.  Also, you could have one thread accepting the command strings and adding them to the queue, and the second thread writing them to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the links in the description. I posted the same question over CodeReview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96398/storing-data-into-an-sql-table-using-multiple-threads-and-queues . I've read the links and I think `AutoResetEvent` is more suitable for this job. I'll combine the resolution from CodeReview and your comment and pst my final code when I have time.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I cannot add my final code as a comment, and I don't want to post as an answer, since it's way too similar to your code. You can check the link above for my final code.

Comment: Looked at your code on the other link - and it looks like you understand everything well.  Good work!